# ng-file-select does not work when request fails

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using `angular-file-upload` in my angular project.
https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

```
<span ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Upload employee list</span>
```

Its working fine for first uplaod but when the upload fails, afterwards it does not work.

Please suggest any workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this fix. Its not actually after just error or failure. The upload calls on change event. So when success or error you have to reset the field.

I called this after success/failure.
now it works fine.

```
$("input#fileSelect").val("");
```

and the span is like

```
<span ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" id="fileSelect">Upload employee list</span>
```